# listview viewHolder leaks memory android

Tags: android

Testing this class for memory issues using MAT i figured out that there 16 objects of the inner class ViewHolder according to the tool, but i do not really understand where the problem occurs. 
Can anyone help me, please?

```
public class InEnglishPlacesDataListCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter implements OnClickListener{

    private ListPlacesFragment activity;
    private SearchPlaceResultListFragment searchPlaceResultListFragment;
    private BitmapTask imgFetcher;
    private Context context;
    private int layout;
    private Cursor cursor;
    private double current_latitude;
    private double current_longtitude;
    private String button_pressed;
    private Boolean imagessavedFlag;
    private Bitmap bitmap;
    private String fontcolor="";
    private Bitmap bit;

    GPSTracker gps;
    ArrayList<PlacesData> placesDataArray = new ArrayList<PlacesData>();


    public InEnglishPlacesDataListCursorAdapter(String button_pressed, SearchPlaceResultListFragment searchPlaceResultListFragment, Context context, int layout, Cursor cursor, String[] from, int[] to, double current_latitude, double current_longtitude, boolean imagessavedFlag, String fontcolor) {
        super(context, layout, cursor, from, to);
        this.button_pressed = button_pressed;
        this.searchPlaceResultListFragment = searchPlaceResultListFragment;
        this.context = context.getApplicationContext();
        this.layout = layout;
        this.cursor = cursor;
        //this.imgFetcher = i;
        this.current_latitude = current_latitude;
        this.current_longtitude = current_longtitude;
        this.imagessavedFlag = imagessavedFlag;
        this.fontcolor = fontcolor;
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public InEnglishPlacesDataListCursorAdapter(String button_pressed, ListPlacesFragment activity, Context context, int layout, Cursor cursor, String[] from, int[] to, double current_latitude, double current_longtitude, boolean imagessavedFlag) {
        super(context, layout, cursor, from, to);
        this.button_pressed = button_pressed;
        this.activity = activity;
        this.context = context;
        this.layout = layout;
        this.cursor = cursor;
        //this.imgFetcher = i;
        this.current_latitude = current_latitude;
        this.current_longtitude = current_longtitude;
        this.imagessavedFlag = imagessavedFlag;
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    private class ViewHolder{
        TextView nametv, placeNametv, distance, latitudetv, longtitudetv, desc_infohiddentv,    menuhiddentv,
        telhiddentv, linkhiddentv, fbLinkhiddentv, emailhiddentv, exhibitionhiddentv,
        photoLink1hiddentv, photoLink2hiddentv, photoLink3hiddentv, photoLink4hiddentv;
        ImageView icon;
        Button infoButton;

        ViewHolder(View v){
            desc_infohiddentv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.descinfohiddentv);
            menuhiddentv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.menuhiddentv);
            telhiddentv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.telhiddentv);
            linkhiddentv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.linkhiddentv);
            fbLinkhiddentv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.fbLinkhiddentv);
            emailhiddentv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.emailhiddentv);
            exhibitionhiddentv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.exhibitionhiddentv);
            photoLink1hiddentv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.photoLink1hiddentv);
            photoLink2hiddentv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.photoLink2hiddentv);
            photoLink3hiddentv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.photoLink3hiddentv);
            photoLink4hiddentv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.photoLink4hiddentv);
            nametv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.locationName);
            placeNametv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.placeNametv);
            latitudetv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.latitudetv);
            longtitudetv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.longtitudetv);
            distance = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.distance);
            icon = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.locationImage);
            infoButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.info_button);
        }
    }



    public View getView(int pos, View inView, ViewGroup parent){
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        //imgFetcher = new BitmapTask(context.getApplicationContext());
        View v = inView;
        ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.places_basic_layout, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
            viewHolder.infoButton.setTag(viewHolder);
            v.setTag(viewHolder);   
        }
        else{
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }
        this.cursor.moveToPosition(pos);
        String name = this.cursor.getString(this.cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
        int integer_id = Integer.parseInt(name);
        String placeNameEl = this.cursor.getString(this.cursor.getColumnIndex("name_en"));
        String image_link = this.cursor.getString(this.cursor.getColumnIndex("photo_link"));
        double place_latitude = this.cursor.getDouble(this.cursor.getColumnIndex("latitude"));
        String str_placelatitude = Double.toString(place_latitude);
        double place_longtitude = this.cursor.getDouble(this.cursor.getColumnIndex("longtitude"));
        String str_placelongtitude = Double.toString(place_longtitude);
        String descInfo = this.cursor.getString(this.cursor.getColumnIndex("info_en"));
        String tel = this.cursor.getString(this.cursor.getColumnIndex("tel"));
        String link = this.cursor.getString(this.cursor.getColumnIndex("link"));
        String fbLink = this.cursor.getString(this.cursor.getColumnIndex("fb_link"));
        String email = this.cursor.getString(this.cursor.getColumnIndex("email"));
        String exhibition = this.cursor.getString(this.cursor.getColumnIndex("exhibition_en"));
        String menu = this.cursor.getString(this.cursor.getColumnIndex("menu_en"));
        String link1 = this.cursor.getString(this.cursor.getColumnIndex("link1"));
        String link2 = this.cursor.getString(this.cursor.getColumnIndex("link2"));
        String link3 = this.cursor.getString(this.cursor.getColumnIndex("link3"));
        String link4 = this.cursor.getString(this.cursor.getColumnIndex("link4"));


        double apostasi = GPSTracker.getDistance(this.current_latitude, this.current_longtitude, place_latitude, place_longtitude);
        double distanceInKm = apostasi/1000;
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
        String dx=df.format(distanceInKm);


        viewHolder.nametv.setText(name);
        viewHolder.desc_infohiddentv.setText(descInfo);
        viewHolder.menuhiddentv.setText(menu);
        viewHolder.telhiddentv.setText(tel);
        viewHolder.linkhiddentv.setText(link);
        viewHolder.fbLinkhiddentv.setText(fbLink);
        viewHolder.emailhiddentv.setText(email);
        viewHolder.exhibitionhiddentv.setText(exhibition);
        viewHolder.photoLink1hiddentv.setText(link1);
        viewHolder.photoLink2hiddentv.setText(link2);
        viewHolder.photoLink3hiddentv.setText(link3);
        viewHolder.photoLink4hiddentv.setText(link4);
        viewHolder.placeNametv.setText(placeNameEl);
        if (fontcolor.equals("black")){ 
            viewHolder.placeNametv.setText(placeNameEl);
            viewHolder.distance.setText(dx + " km");
            viewHolder.distance.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            viewHolder.distance.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            viewHolder.placeNametv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            viewHolder.placeNametv.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        }
        else{
            viewHolder.placeNametv.setText(placeNameEl);
            viewHolder.distance.setText(dx + " km");
        }
        //viewHolder.surnametv.setTag(surname);
        viewHolder.latitudetv.setText(str_placelatitude);
        viewHolder.longtitudetv.setText(str_placelongtitude);
        viewHolder.infoButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        return v;
    }
    ![][1]
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //TextView surnametv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.nameEl);
        //Button pressed = (Button) v;
        //String button_pressed_text = pressed.getText().toString();
        Log.i("Button pressed text =>", " " + button_pressed);

        ViewHolder vH = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        //String url = (String) vH.surnametv.getTag();
        //Toast.makeText(this.context, url, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), PlacesDetailsTabs.class);
        //Intent intent = new Intent(this.activity, PlacesListFragmentActivityTest.class);
        //intent.putExtra("nameEl", vH.surnametv.getTag().toString());
        String str_current_latitude = Double.toString(current_latitude);
        String str_current_longtitude = Double.toString(current_longtitude);
        intent.putExtra("language", "English");
        intent.putExtra("current latitude" , str_current_latitude);
        intent.putExtra("current longtitude", str_current_longtitude);
        intent.putExtra("placeNameEl", vH.placeNametv.getText());
        intent.putExtra("desc_info", vH.desc_infohiddentv.getText());
        intent.putExtra("menu", vH.menuhiddentv.getText());
        intent.putExtra("telephone", vH.telhiddentv.getText());
        intent.putExtra("link", vH.linkhiddentv.getText());
        intent.putExtra("fbLink", vH.fbLinkhiddentv.getText());
        intent.putExtra("email", vH.emailhiddentv.getText());
        intent.putExtra("exhibition", vH.exhibitionhiddentv.getText());
        intent.putExtra("photoLink1", vH.photoLink1hiddentv.getText());
        intent.putExtra("photoLink2", vH.photoLink2hiddentv.getText());
        intent.putExtra("photoLink3", vH.photoLink3hiddentv.getText());
        intent.putExtra("photoLink4", vH.photoLink4hiddentv.getText());
        intent.putExtra("latitude", vH.latitudetv.getText());
        intent.putExtra("longtitude", vH.longtitudetv.getText());
        intent.putExtra("button_pressed_text", button_pressed);
        intent.putExtra("displaycurrentPoint", "yes");
        //Toast.makeText(this.context, vH.photoLink1hiddentv.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //intent.putExtra("latitude", this.c.getDouble(this.c.getColumnIndex("latitude")));
        //intent.putExtra("longtitude", this.c.getDouble(this.c.getColumnIndex("longtitude")));
        if (this.activity == null){
            this.searchPlaceResultListFragment.startActivity(intent);
        }else{
            this.activity.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: the adapter is inside the ListPlacesFragment class which extends ListFragment and the following command : setListAdapter(new InEnglishPlacesDataListCursorAdapter(button_pressed, this, getActivity(),  R.layout.places_basic_layout, cursor, columns, to, current_latitude, current_longtitude, imagessavedFlag) ); calls it.

Comment: I think i figured out where the problem was...i moved the ViewHolder class from inside the Adapter Class to the ListFragment class...the instances of ViewHolder are now 1...thank you guys for your help...

Comment: Why do you think that having 16 instances of ViewHolder is a problem?

Comment: I have not yet entirelly figured out how the ViewHolder pattern operates...There is no problem that every row of list view holds a reference to a relative layout and this layout holds a reference to the entire view respectively. Isn't it?

Comment: Every row **should** have its own ViewHolder object because each row has its own View objects. The point of this pattern is to save time by avoiding costly calls to findViewById().

Comment: The last few days i have read a lot of documentation about this subject..i think i have almost grasp how the pattern works...thank's for your help Code-Apprentice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make the ViewHolder class as static inner class.

Just add

```
static class ViewHolder{}
```

This is avoid multiple object formation of viewHolder.

Follow this tutorial ,will help you understand list view better https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70

Comment: I have hust tried it but the number of Objects remains 16.

Comment: ViewHolder viewHolder = null; take it as instance variable

Comment: ViewHolder viewHolder = null; take this out side getView()

Comment: Again, this is not the problem

Comment: A static inner class doesn't change the number of instances of that class. It only means you don't need an instance of the surrounding class to use it.

Answer (score 0):

There is plenty of things you should see.

1st you must knew that getView function is called everytime you scroll your list or with each item you insert.
So, the cracks of my point is that your getView function should be neat and clean.
Means it just shows value not to populate it inside the getView.

Precautions :

1) Check connectivity outside the adapter.

2) Create a static viewHolder class so that it will be created once.

3) you must populate a ArrayList of objects outside getView and then use that List inside getView.

Comment: " Create a static viewHolder class so that it will be created once." What do you mean by this? What will only be created once?

Comment: As I remember static variables are created at compiler time, not run time so that it can not be created in run time